# JQuery Widget Factory - Bind an event listener after initialization not working -

Tags: jquery, widget

I'm attempting to extend JQuery.ui.draggable using the widget factory. Everything seems to be working fine until I go to setup an event after its been initialized, at which point my event binding doesn't seem to work. In other scenarios, like setting up the event on init, works.

```
//
// extend jquery ui draggable
//
$.widget("ui.drag2", $.ui.draggable, {
     options: {
        shiftable: false,
        shiftContainer: null,
        shiftableSelKeys: {}
     }
     _initShiftable: function () {},
     _shiftTarget: function () {}

});

// 
// after the above is defined, i can call this below, and draggable works //(effectively inheriting from ui.draggable and containing all my new members
//
$('.myClass').drag2(); 

// 
// I can also do this, and get a custom callback bound to drag (msg)
//
$('.myClass').drag2({
    drag: function (ui, evt) {
       console.log(' -- dragging -- ');
   }
}); 

// But this Doesn't work ?
// I don't understand why binding the event after its been intialized doesn't // work
$('.myClass').on('drag', function (ui, evt) { console.log('-- dragging --'); }); // Doesn't work ?
```

Comment: worked for me http://jsfiddle.net/396audpt/

Comment: You're not using the widget factory to extend. See the top of my example again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to define the private method, _setOption, for my plugin. This applies the option you're passing to the parent widget you're inheriting from. Since I'm relying on their implementation of drag, I needed to apply the option to the parent widget.

```
$.widget("ui.drag2", $.ui.draggable, {
    options: {
        shiftable: false,
        shiftContainer: null,
        shiftableSelKeys: {}
    },
     _setOption: function (key, value) {
        // invoke setOption for draggable
        this._super(key, value);
        this._superApply(arguments);
    }

});

// setting drag callback
$('.target').drag2('option', 'drag', function (){ console.log('hello world'); );
```